# CocoapodsのResourcesにあるファイルが自動でビルドされない？

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods

cocoapodsでいくつかのライブラリをインストールしました。その中に含まれているResourcesにある、Localizableや画像ファイルについて、ビルドしてもアプリにインストールされていない状態になっています。

例えば、CTFeedbackのCTFeedbackLocalizable.stringsやAQSLINEActivityのcolor_AQSLINEActivity.pngなどがアプリに反映されない状況です。

Podfileは以下のようです。（幾つか他のものは省略していますが）

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

pod 'CTFeedback'
pod "AQSLINEActivity"
```

.xcworkspaceとPodsディレクトリを一度削除してpodsの再インストールしましたが改善しませんでした。

どのようにすることで、自動的にビルドされるのでしょうか？どこを確認すべきでしょうか？
もしくは手動でビルドするものなのでしょうか？

よろしくお願いします。